# Reference of methods

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, methods

I'm developing a library to IOS, which at some point need to create a `NSArray` of methods reference´s from various classes. To an single class that will at some point call them.

Any ideas how to do that??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some options. You can use `NSStrings` to actually have the name of your methods and then just do:

```
NSString *myMethodName = @"hellWorld";
SEL selector = selectorFromString(myMethodName);
```

You can then add your selector to your `NSArray`.

You can also use `NSInvocations` and store the methods and define the target later:

> An NSInvocation object contains all the elements of an Objective-C
>   message: a target, a selector, arguments, and the return value. Each
>   of these elements can be set directly, and the return value is set
>   automatically when the NSInvocation object is dispatched.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Edit 1 (for the fun of it):**

```
- (Method *)getMethodsPointer{
    unsigned int number = 0;

    Method *myMethods = class_copyMethodList([self class], &number);

    //for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    // {
    //    printf("%s",sel_getName(method_getName(myMethods[i])));
    //}
    return myMethods;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a selector to your `array`. You create a selector like this:

`-(void)myMethod:(int)something`

`SEL selectorToMyMethod = @selector(myMethod:);`

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: Oh, I forgot SEL is not an object, but you can always convert them to one, like this:[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(x)]

Comment: how can i call it later from another class?

Comment: You send the "performSelector" message to your object: [myObject performSelector:@selector(selectorToMyMethod)];

Comment: You can store `NSString's` and then convert them to selectors... But I prefer the `NSInvocation` way, I think its cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

You could create some NSInvocations, store the Selectors and the target classes in it, and add the NSInvocation to the Array.

Storing the selectors only is possible, but only if the methods are in one class only - because Selectors are independant from their class.

Comment: You can actually call a selector on an object that doesn't respond to it. You will actually have to deal with that later with `forwardInvocation:`. That's a way of creating multiple inheritance.